# Maximum number reached for Sharepoint 2007 number-type column

Tags: list

In a SharePoint 2007 List, there is a number-type column which have a maximum value 1000. Suppose that the column is used for a auto-increment ID, what will happen if the ID exceed 1000?

Will the next ID be reset to 0 or a error will occur?